# React - Method always runs 1 step too late.

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an application that displays a list of items that can be filtered by type and 'development point' by the user. Both the 'type' and 'development point' are selected from a dropdown menu.

There is a small twist to this rather standard setup in the sense that the choices in the dropdowns are determined by the filtered output. 
For example: if no items with the type 'assessment' have the 'education' development point (and I filter by 'assessment')  the choice 'education' will disappear from the 'development point' dropdown menu.

I've created a setup that uses 3 components:

1 A main component. 
2 A component for the filter that sets the 'type_filter' & 'developmentpointfilter' in the main component
3. A straightforward 'listdisplay' component that displays all the results.

The 'Main component' has two methods that deal with the filter:

A: the 'setFilter' method, which is passed as a prop to the '' . component and is set everytime the user sets a filter - this sets the  'type_filter' & 'developmentpointfilter' in the main component

```
setFilter(value, key) {
        //Set state filters to the right values.
        this.setState({[key] : value})
        this.Filter()
    }
```

B: The 'Filter' method. Which gets the 'item list' and filters it down untill only the relevant items remain, which are then passed to the 'list display' component.

```
Filter() {

        //No filters are set, so show all results
        if (this.state.developmentpoint_filter === "" && this.state.type_filter === "" && this.state.subject_filter === "") {
            this.setState({filtered_items: this.state.items})
        }

        let filtered_items = new Set();

        for (let item of this.state.items.results) {

            //Iterate over items and compare with items if applicable.
            if (this.state.type_filter[0] && this.state.type_filter[0]!=="") {
                if (item.type === this.state.type_filter) {
                    console.log('match!');
                    filtered_items.add(item)
                }
            }

            if (this.state.developmentpoint_filter[0] && this.state.developmentpoint_filter[0]!=="") {
                for (let category of item.categories) {

                    if (category.name === this.state.developmentpoint_filter) {
                        console.log('match!');
                        filtered_items.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }

            if (this.state.subject_filter[0] && this.state.subject_filter[0]!=="") {
                if (item.subject === this.state.subject_filter) {
                    console.log('match!');
                    filtered_items.add(item)
                }
            }
        }

        //Turn the results into a array, that can be used for further processing.
        filtered_items = Array.from(filtered_items);

        if (filtered_items.length > 0) {
            console.log('ik doe mijn ding')
            // Filters are active and results are active
            this.setState({
                filtered_items: {'results' :filtered_items},
                no_results: false,
            });

        }

        if (filtered_items.length < 1){
            // Filters are active but no results are found
            this.setState({
                filtered_items: {'results' :[]},
                no_results: true,
            });
        }

        console.log(this.state.filtered_items);
        this.setState({flup: this.state.filtered_items});
    }
```

As you can see the 'Filter' method is called in the 'setFilter' method, after the state has been updated to include the new filters.

This setup seems like something that should work, yet I run in the following problem: The 'filtered_items' array in the state is always one step behind the rest of the program. I print the value of this array to the console, and this array always represents the value that should have been displayed the previous time I clicked on the filter.

If 2 items should be displayed, but this is my first click, it will display the full list. 
If I then adjust the filters so that just 1 item should be displayed, it will display (and print to console) the 2 items from the previous query, etc, etc.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Invoke your filter function inside the setState callback. Like so: `this.state({[key] : value}, () => {this.Filter()})`. This guarantees that filter runs **after** the state is updated.

Comment: This solved it! Thank you so very much!

Comment: No worries. Checkout the official docs. There is a section about `setState` and its callback.